# How to launch external application that keeps alive after closing the calling program in C#?

Tags: c#, process, external

My target is to call an external program from my C# application and keep it alive even when my application is closing. 
Both applications don't share anything and I could accomplish the same task by running a command from the command line by passing in a few arguments.

I've been trying to use the process class and I've been fiddling around with DTE, both let me create an instance of the external program (Visual Studio to be precise) but they will close as soon as the calling application is closing.

Is there any other way? Maybe a call to Windows, that will launch that program instead of my application?

Comment: when you Process.Start an external app it keeps alive regardless of the calling app that shelled/spawned the new process... isn't what your asking by design behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).